# " The goal was his to achieve" - What structure is it?

Tags: grammar

> *When Hillary tried to climb Everest, the goal was his to achieve.*

I saw this today and it seems a bit strange to me. From what I understand, *"to achieve"* is a noun and we can put a *possessive adjective* before it. But is this pattern used often? I don't think I've seen it very much.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. The goal was his to achieve.
> 2. The goal was for him to achieve.

Both the sentences are correct and mean the same.

> The goal was his to achieve.

In this sentence **The goal** is the subject of the sentence, verb is **was** and predicate is **his to achieve**.

Now leave **to achieve** and the sentence will reduce to **The goal was his**. **His** is a possessive pronoun, modifying **the goal**. **The goal is his** - this sentence clearly says whose goal it is.

Now add **to achieve**. The sentence becomes - **The goal was his to achieve**. Now **to achieve** part is for **his** task.

Yes this kind of pattern occurs often and very natural and correct.

Is this clear now?

Comment: What if it's not "his" but "her" ? So it would be "the goal was hers" and "The goal was hers to achieve".?

Comment: Correct. And another variety is "for her to achieve". Both bears the same meaning.

Comment: So I must use a possessive pronoun in my example, not a possessive adjective? But why my fist understanding is wrong ? I mean we can consider that "to achieve" is a noun and her/his is a possessive adjective and we usually can put a possessive adjective before a noun.

Comment: I think "his", "hers" etc are possessive pronoun. Never knew they are possessive adjectives as well. No idea. But there is no issue of your considering "to achieve" as a noun, in my opinion.